# AS3 StageVideo, how to determine when ended?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, video

Using this SimpleStageVideo wrapper for an AS3 AIR videoplayer.

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=2571

I need to determine when the video has ended but can see no events that are triggered.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StageVideo` and `Video` both use `NetStream` (which is the actual video content).   That is where you listen for events related to the content.

So if you're currently playing a video using the component you link to, you should already have a `NetStream` object.

Here is an example:

```
var stream:NetStream = ...//your net stream object you should already have to play the video, assumption here is you already have it instantiated.

stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler,false,0,true);

function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    switch (event.info.code) {
        case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
            //the video wasn't found, better tell the user something
            break;

        case "NetStream.Play.Start":
            //video started playing
            break;

        case "NetStream.Play.Stop":
            videoFinishedHandler(); //do something now that the video is finished playing
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want to see a list of all the other NetStream Status events you can intercept, see [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html)

Comment: thanks, more importantly, trying to figure out how to properly use  multiple stageVideo objects. No surprise that there is a lack of documentation! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659660/as3-stagevideo-controlling-depth-of-multiple-stage-video-instances