# AS3 StageVideo > controlling depth of multiple stage video instances

Tags: actionscript-3, video, stagevideo

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html

According to the documentation the stageVideo object exposes a depth property which allows you to set the z depth.

But am confused on how to implement.
There is  a read only vector object

```
stage.stageVideos[0];
```

but how exactly do you populate this vector with more than one StageVideo object? Nowhere in the documentation does it explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stage.stageVideos` array is pre-populated with the amount of stage video objects the system supports.  So you don't have to do anything there. That number can change though based off app size and other things, so it's important to listen for the stage video availability events and react accordingly.

To change the z-order, you use the `depth` property of a `StageVideo` instance:

```
var stgVideo1:StageVideo = stage.stageVideos[0];
stgVideo.depth = 2;

//if the system supports more than 1, lets grab a reference to another stage video
if(stage.stageVideos.length > 1){
    var stgVideo2:StageVideo = stage.stageVideos[1];
    stgVideo2.depth = 1;
}
```

This will make `stgVideo2` behind the first one.   All things being equal (same depth value, or none specified) the depth will be the same order as the stage.stageVideos array.

For more information, [read the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html#depth)

Comment: Thanks, but as to reading the documentation, its pretty sparse!

Comment: Also a bit confused as to how the stageVideos vector gets populated. Or can it be thought of merely as a pointer to an empty 'slot' that the corresponding video (passed in to the attached Netstream object) gets played?

Comment: Think of it more as a system constant.  Like something in the capabilities class.    It's a list of all the stage videos instances your system could handle.    I agree it's not the most intuitive way to have set that up.